# How to ask user permission for using Geolocation again after user has denied it once?

Tags: geolocation, windows-8, winjs

In Windows 8, javascript metro apps,  if the user denies the permission to use Geolocation, then the permission always remains denied.

Maybe the user denied permission to use Geolocation when using the app for the first time but later might be willing to allow use of geolocation as trust is built. But I could not find how to ask for permission again.

Even in the Win8 Geolocation sample, once the permission is denied then it remains denied and there is no way to ask for permission again.

Is it possible to ask the user for permissions again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always prompt the user with a flyout or a message dialog, you just can't initiate a geolocation query and cause the core capability question to fire. Users will learn soon enough that capabilities are configurable in your apps Settings | Permissions flyout and you can even point them there to change their answer.

In other words, I think the platform is avoiding the scenario where the user says, "Would you leave me alone?! I don't want to be bothered about my privacy!" and if the developer is careful about his workflow then I doubt it will be too difficult to avoid the scenario where the user says "Hey! I want to this app to get smarter about my location but I don't know how to enable that."
Subjective I know, but you can see how it favors the user.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a Toast notification but like Jeremy says if you get to annoying with it you could drive users away.